# ¿Alguien sabe solucionar este Error: Invalid block en shopify-liquid?

Tags: imagen, slider, liquid, shopify

Estoy tratando de duplicar una función para insertar imágenes en una sección de la pagina para un slider, la idea es duplicar el que ya existe pero no he podido entender como duplicar porque siempre que lo inserto en shopify me muestra error. Alguien me puede ayudar?

Error: Invalid block 'custom_banner': setting with id="image" id is already taken

```html
{
        "type": "custom_banner_slider",
        "name": "Custom Banner Slider",
        "limit": 2,
        "settings": [
        {
          "type": "color",
          "id": "color",
          "label": "Color",
          "default": "#c33940"
        },
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "image1",
          "label": "Main image 1"
        },
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "image2",
          "label": "Main image 2"
        },
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "image3",
          "label": "Main image 3"
        },
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "image4",
          "label": "Main image 4"
        },
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "image5",
          "label": "Main image 5"
        },
        {
          "type": "header",
          "content": "Text"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "title1",
          "label": "Title 1",
          "default": "Titulo"
        },
        {
          "type": "textarea",
          "id": "info1",
          "label": "Info 1",
          "default": "<p>info</p>"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "title2",
          "label": "Title 2",
         "default": "Titulo"
        },
        {
          "type": "textarea",
          "id": "info2",
          "label": "Info 2",
        "default": "<p>info</p>"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "title3",
          "label": "Title 3",
          "default": "Titulo"
        },
        {
          "type": "textarea",
          "id": "info3",
          "label": "Info 3",
        "default": "<p>info</p>"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "title4",
          "label": "Title 4",
          "default": "Titulo"
        },
        {
          "type": "textarea",
          "id": "info4",
          "label": "Info 4",
            "default": "<p>info</p>"
        }
        ]
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

Procura tener una estructura ordenada y no copiar el código sin entender. El nombre de las variables también es importante, no trates de nombrarlas var1,var2, var3.

Veo que no tienes id en esta parte:

```
 {
     "type": "header",
      "content": "Text"
   },
```

Te pongo un ejemplo completo para que puedas entender mejor:

```
{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Text Box",
    "settings": [
      {
        "id": "text-box",
        "type": "text",
        "label": "Heading",
        "default": "Title"
      },
      {
        "id": "text",
        "type": "richtext",
        "label": "Add custom text below",
        "default": "<p>Add your text here</p>"
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a probar nuevamente